# how do i filter an javascript object and get the desired output as array?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

```
[
  {imgUrl: "A"},
  {imgUrl: "B"},
  {imgUrl: "C", file: {fileName: "D"} }  
]
```

Desired output = ["A", "B", "D"];

Comment: You're looking for [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), not filter

Comment: this is my Desired output = ["A", "B", "D"];

Comment: Just follow the link above

Comment: which link are you talking about?

Comment: And what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj=[
         {imgUrl: "A"},
         {imgUrl: "B"},
         {imgUrl: "C", file: {fileName: "D"} }  
       ];
    var y=obj.map(function(z)
     {

      if(typeof(z.file) !== 'undefined')
       {
         return z.file.fileName;

       }
       else
       {
          return z.imgUrl;
       }
     });

 y is your desired array.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and some condition to handle your requirement.

```
array.map((value) => {
  if (value.file && value.file.fileName) {
    return value.file.fileName;
  }

  return value.imgUrl;
});
```